# Como ler comentários de uma classe, função ou método?

Tags: php, reflexão

Já vi algumas implementações no framework Symfony e Laravel que permitem definir através de comentários 
rotas em métodos de controller, ou as definições de annotation dos Models do Doctrine.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
class Usuariosontroller

{
    /**
     * @Route('GET', 'usuarios')
    */
    public function getIndex()
    {

    }

}
```

Como os frameworks fazem pra ler esse bloco de comentários em cima dos métodos?

Comment: [ReflectionClass](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2gbPukrSPLw/hqdefault.jpg)

Comment: @HomerSimpson responde aí pra ganhar votos, cara

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Classe

Utilizando o [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.reflectionclass.php) para acessar a classe, e assim obter o valor do comentário utilizando o método [`getDocComment`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php):

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass('Usuariosontroller');
echo $reflection->getDocComment();
```

Exemplo [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/cRqgo6).

### Método

Utilizando ainda o [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.reflectionclass.php) para acessar a classe, agora utilize o [`getMethod`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reflectionclass.getmethod.php) para acessar o método que deseja obter a informação, utilizando o método [`getDocComment`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php):

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass('Usuariosontroller'); 
echo $reflection->getMethod('getIndex')->getDocComment();
```

Exemplo [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/u14WIZ).

### Função

Utilize o [`ReflectionFunction`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.reflectionfunction.php) para acessar a função, em sequência o [`getDocComment`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php) para acessar o comentário:

```
$reflection = new ReflectionFunction('beber');
$reflection->getDocComment()
```

Exemplo [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/jaKIty).

#### Observação:

Existem algumas formas de se fazer um comentário, porém, os métodos acima funcionaram somente se utilizar o comentário cujo token seja `T_DOC_COMMENT`, ou seja, comentários que obedeçam a syntax: `/** */`, então comentários que utilizem o token `T_COMMENT` - syntax `// or #, and /* */` - serão ignorados.

Comment: Show de bola, ficou bonito. Accept

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode usar **[token_get_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php)** nativo do php.

arquivo **index.php**

```
/**

    COMENTÁRIO

*/

function foo(){
    echo "foo";
}
```

*Executando...*

```
$array = token_get_all(file_get_contents("index.php"));

foreach($array as $arr){
    if(isset($arr[0]) && ($arr[0] == T_DOC_COMMENT || $arr[0] == T_COMMENT)){
        print_r($arr[1]);
    }
}
```

saída:

> /** COMENTÁRIO */